# Condition for primeness of a degree 2 Solinas Prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, cryptography

Given $2^{2k+1}+2^{k+1}+1$ is prime, this necessarily imply $2k+1$ is a prime.
This result is assumed true in *Primality tests for $2^p \pm 2^{(p+1)/2}+1$ using elliptic curves by YU TSUMURA in Proceedings of the American mathematical society vol. 139 num. 8 August 2011 Pages 2697-2703* and also considered easy to prove in that paper, but I didnt find anything in the web and the only fact I found that may  help to prove this is $(2^{2k+1}+2^{k+1}+1)(2^{2k+1}-2^{k+1}+1)=2^{2(2k+1)}+1$.

Comment: This is not a do-my-homework-for-me site.

Comment: The obvious thing to do first is to search...have you done that?  I just threw it onto WA and it looks like $k=25,34,42$ are counterexamples.  No?

Comment: @lulu: Are you sure those are counterexamples?

Comment: @quasi  Well, no.  I threw it up hastily.  Might have gotten it wrong.  I'll check.

Comment: @quasi.  there's a bug in what I wrote...none of those examples work.  I'll search deeper.

Comment: @lulu: I'll save you time. The claim holds for $1\le k\le 10^3$. So the claim has empirical support, but if the claim actually holds, the question is _why_? Interesting question, but it as is sometimes (but not always!) the case, a bare question gets closed (and in this case, _very_ quickly!)

Comment: @quasi  Thanks!  I was looking at $2^{2k+1}+2^k+1$ if that matters.  Obviously wrong.

Comment: @quasi  Maybe I still have a bug...I am finding remarkable few primes.  Is that what you see?

Comment: Well, now I am seeing no counterexample but largely because there are almost no test cases.

Comment: Oh, right! For $1\le k \le 3000$, the test cases which satisfy the hypothesis are only these: $k=1, 2, 5, 9, 14, 78, 81, 141, 189, 498$.

Comment: @quasi same list I have.  Good!

Comment: I have searched and found nothing!

Comment: @user599179: As you can see, your question was put on hold, so potential answers are blocked. Since you are a new member, perhaps you're not aware that you are expected to include some context (e.g., where the problem comes from, what you have tried) as part of your post, rather than just a question.

Comment: @user599179  How far have you searched?  As I say, there are very, very few primes in the list for small $k$...so I wouldn't want to deduce much.

Comment: Note:  I would gladly vote to reopen the question if you add  search results to the post and, maybe, explain the context behind the question.

Comment: @Alex Francisco: What makes you think this is a homework question? Maybe it is, but I don't see any immediate way to answer it. Usually I regard problems as homework problems if they are known, standard problems, and I can see an immediate resolution.

Comment: [A006599](http://oeis.org/A006599) There are no counterexamples below $10^4$.

Comment: @ quasi: thank you very much for helping me to learn how to ask my questions here. this problem assumed to be true in a paper and I added the name in question.

Comment: If $2^{2k+1}+2^{k+1}+1$ is prime, then consider that expression mod $5$. You can conclude that $k\equiv1$ or $k\equiv2$ mod $4$. (Mod $4$, because $\varphi(5)=4$.) From that you may conclude that $2k+1\equiv3$ or $2k+1\equiv5$ mod $8$. I'm unsure if this helps of course. But now if you assume that $2^{2k+1}+2^{k+1}+1$ is prime, it requires these conditions on $k$. Maybe they can assist with establishing the additional condition on $k$ that you seek (that $2k+1$ must be prime.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We begin with the following identity applied on $x=2^k$.

$$4x^4+1=(2x^2+2x+1)(2x^2-2x+1).$$

This gives that

$$\left(2^{2k+1}+2^{k+1}+1\right)\left(2^{2k+1}-2^{k+1}+1\right)=2^{4k+2}+1.$$

Assume for contradiction that $2k+1$ is not prime, but our first factor is prime. Let $p$ be a prime dividing $2k+1$. We have that, as $\frac{2k+1}{p}$ is odd,

$$x^p+1\big| x^{2k+1}+1,$$

which applied at $x=4$ gives

$$2^{2p}+1\big | 2^{4k+2}+1.$$

However, as $p$ is a proper divisor of $2k+1$, $2p\leq 2k+1$, so

$$2^{2p}+1\leq 2^{2k+1}+1 < 2^{2k+1}+2^{k+1}+1,$$

so $2^{2p}+1$ is not our first factor, and, as our first factor is prime, it cannot share any common factors with $2^{2p}+1$. This means that

$$2^{2p}+1 \big|2^{2k+1}-2^{k+1}+1.$$

As $2k+1=mp$ for some odd $m=2n+1$, we have that

$$2^{2k+1} = 2^{mp} \equiv 2^{2np+p}\equiv (-1)^n2^p\bmod \left(2^{2p}+1\right),$$

and similarly

$$2^{k+1} = 2^{\frac{(2n+1)p+1}{2}} = 2^{np+\left(\frac{p+1}{2}\right)}\equiv 2^{\frac{p+1}{2}}K\bmod \left(2^{2p}+1\right),$$

where $K$ is in the orbit of $2^p\bmod \left(2^{2p}+1\right)$; in particular, we may choose

$$K\in\left\{1,2^p,-1,-2^p\right\}.$$

Thus, we have

$$2^{2p}+1\bigg|(-1)^n 2^p - 2^{\frac{p+1}{2}}K+1.$$

As $p\geq 1$, both of the first two terms of the right side are clearly even, while $1$ is odd, which implies that the right side is odd and thus nonzero. As a result, its magnitude is $\geq 2^{2p}+1$, which implies that

$$2^{2p}+1\leq \left|(-1)^n 2^p - 2^{\frac{p+1}{2}}K+1\right|\leq 2^p\left(1+2^{\frac{p+1}{2}}\right)+1$$

$$2^p\leq 1+2^{\frac{p+1}{2}}.$$

$$x^2\leq 2+2x$$

for $x=2^{\frac{p+1}{2}}$. This is clearly false for $x\geq 3$, and as $p$ is odd, $2^{\frac{p+1}{2}}\geq 4$, and we have a contradiction.